# Option to run software on installation of disc has disappered

Tags: bluetooth

Been struggling with getting net access for my tower for awhile now.

Finally gave up on a bluetooth doggle and bought a PCI card that says its Linux is compatible.

When i inserted the software disc, nothing happens other than Ubuntu recognizing there is a disc.

So I went into setting, thinking I had turned off automatic installation under the default applications tab.

There is no “other media” or software tab there now!?

Did I inadvertently break Ubuntu 18.04 somehow?

Comment: Wired or wireless net access? What model card? Did the kernel recognise the card (`sudo lshw`)? Drivers-in-the-package is usually for Windows; did the disc specify the need to install Linux drivers?

Comment: wireless access - through my cell phone or iPad  SCSI the disc didn't do anything except appear on the desktop  it came without installation instructions of any kind and you're probably right that it's set up for windows installation first.  card model number : PCE-AC51 Wireless-AC750

Comment: Most devices are autodetected by the Linux kernel; a setup disc is usually unnecessary. Hence the question about `lshw`...which is really the important question.

Comment: I entered lshw and got back the letter I sent before.   —- > SCSI

Comment: Either your system is broken or you didn't wait long enough -- the correct output of `sudo lshw` is enormous.

Comment: youre right 22,000+ characters too long for here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106915/discussion-between-micheal-rainwater-and-user535733).